# snakemake gives all messages twice

Tags: snakemake, esgf

Snakemake is giving me a lot of extra warnings and info, many of them twice. How do I turn this behaviour off?

See screen shot below:
[image]

### Now with reprex

I've been able to track the source of the problem down, and bottled it up into a minimum working example. Try running this snakefile:

```
from pyesgf.search import SearchConnection

people = ['Amy', 'Bruce']

rule person:
    output: '{person}.txt'
    run:
        print(f'\n This person is called {wildcards.person}!\n')

rule people:
    input: expand('{person}.txt',person=people)
```

With the import present, the extra logging messages are present. Commenting it out gets rid of it.

Versions:

- esgf-pyclient=0.3.1=pyh1a96a4e_2
- snakemake=7.32.4=hdfd78af_0

Comment: you can try with snakemake --quiet

Comment: I have tried all three options with --quiet:
* rules and progress give an identical output to that above
* all gives total silence
I'm trying to find the middle way, of only getting a message once!

Comment: snakemake version?

Comment: Version 7.25.3, which seems to be the latest version available via micromamba - it's drawing its packages from bioconda and conda-forge

Comment: Managed to upgrade to 7.32.4 - no change in symptoms..

Comment: strange, It's working in my environment with same version. You can try to set the quiet option in your Snakefile or configuration file. Open your Snakefile and add the following line: quiet: True

Comment: Are you adding additional logging in your snakefile or scripts?  Can you share it?

Comment: No, there's no logging explicitly declared  in either the scripts or the snakefile at all - but it does look like it is logging (see e.g. `snakemake.logging` references) I am wondering if there is a system-level flag that turns logging on that I may have overlooked. Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Post your snakefile, preferably a minimal version that gives that behavior.

Comment: Have edited original question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from esgf-pyclient's [logging code](https://github.com/ESGF/esgf-pyclient/blob/master/pyesgf/search/connection.py#L41) which adds another handler to the logger.  When snakemake logs some output it gets handled twice, once by esgf (lines like `WARNING:snakemake...`) and once by snakemake (lines like `Building DAG of jobs` with color).

There's an argument that snakemake should disallow other loggers, but it's equally useful if a module has important logging information.  Either way, it seems like you can:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('pyesgf.search').disabled = True
```

after you import pyesgf.  *I didn't test this so the name may not be correct.*